# Stop scroll to top after removing an item from woocommerce cart page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Whenever I remove a product from cart page on woocommerce it scrolls to top. I managed to do that for quantity change but its not working when removing item.

this is Working with quantity change. I want to stop scrolling to top after deleting a product from cart page. Searched everywhere didn't get any answer.

```
var timeout;
 
jQuery( function( $ ) {
        $('.woocommerce').on('change', 'input.qty', function(){

            if ( timeout !== undefined ) {
                clearTimeout( timeout );
            }

            timeout = setTimeout(function() {
                $("[name='update_cart']").trigger("click");
                document.location.reload(true);
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: This is related to theme. We don't know which theme you have and how it handled the stuff. Does it deleted the product through AJAX call or does it deletes it with full page reload? Can you post some additional code from the theme page, related to the delete operation.

Comment: @KeralPatel Not theme related. Woocommerce does that by default. Deleted the product through ajax call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I haven't found a nice solution to this anywhere. So went into the code of woocommerce and changed some code.

Open this file wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/includes/wc-template-functions.php
and search for this at line 3640.

```
wc_print_notices();
```

and comment or remove this line. then it will work for change in quantity and removing items from cart and it won't scroll to top every time when you have 100's of products.

Also you don't need to use `document.location.reload(true);` for this.

P.S. You have to change it every time when you update the plugin.

Answer (score 2):

```php
remove_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'woocommerce_output_all_notices', 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(document).ajaxComplete(function() {
    if ($('body').hasClass('woocommerce-checkout') || $('body').hasClass('woocommerce-cart')) {
        jQuery( 'html, body' ).stop();
    }
  });
});
```

Only this worked for me, if you dont want disable woocommerce notices.
Add this code wrapped on `<script>...</script>` tag in the footer

Answer (score 0):

Try fixing it in CSS by adding

```
body {
    overflow-x: visible !important;
}
```